# Is pre-compiled Qt 5.9 VS version independent?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qt5.9

On the Qt website, in the download section, there is a pre-compiled Qt5.9 available.

Before Qt5.9 there were different pre-compiled packages for each Visual Studio version.

Is new pre-compiled Qt5.9 VS version independent?
If not, for which version is it?

Comment: You may try to download and check. Now there are everything in one package. Btw, I recommend you to use an online installer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not. It can't be since visual c++ versions are usually* not binary compatible (*just now Visual Studio 2017 is binary compatible with 2015).

That package just has different versions you can install, to target Windows: VS2013 (x64), VS2015(x64 and x86), VS2017(x64), MinGW and to target Android (arm and x86).